# Django save multiple view variables

Tags: python, django, webhooks

I'm trying to save URL parameters to my model. Already tried many things and currently getting argument error. Can't find proper documentation on this most likely because I am not sure what the proper search term is.

All I need to do is save webhook POST to my URL. I will use @require_POST decorator to require POST only. Atm this is not the issue. The issue is simply saving the webhook.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Webhook(models.Model):
    clientAccnum = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    clientSubacc = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    eventType = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    eventGroupType = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    subscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    time_stamp_local = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def webhook(request):
    template_name = 'payment/index.html'

    hook = Webhook.save()
    hook.client_acc_num = request.GET.get('clientAccnum')
    hook.client_sub_acc = request.GET.get('clientSubacc')
    hook.event_type = request.GET.get('eventType')
    hook.event_group_type = request.GET.get('eventGroupType')
    hook.sub_id = request.GET.get('subscriptionId')

    hook.time_stamp = request.GET.get('timestamp')
    hook.time_stamp_local = timezone.now()

    hook.save()

    return render(request, template_name)
```

Current error message:

TypeError at /payment/webhook/
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: If you get an error, you need to show it in your question.

Comment: Although if you're getting a POST, why are you consistently accessing request.GET?

Comment: The reason I didn't post error is because I'm trying many things a the moment and think the better way to build what I am trying to do might be obvious for someone with more experience.  Also, this is just for tests since I can't test with POST. Will switch it to POST when I figure out everything I need to do with the payload.

Comment: Well there is no way to help you if you won't say what's going wrong.

Comment: (I have posted error message from above) I'm trying really hard to figure this out and will fix the question. Just let me know what you need. Again I feel like my approach altogether may be wrong so I put less focus on current error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.save()` directly on the class. It's an instance method, so it needs to be called on an instance.

I'm not sure why you want to call save at the start anyway. You call it at the end, to save the data you've set.

Replace that second line with just `hook = Webhook()`.

Comment: Exactly why I didn't post my exact error, It was irrelevant in this case.

Comment: No, it was precisely and completely relevant, pointing to the exact problem.

Comment: How so? I'm not trying to say you wrong, just trying to learn so I can post better question next time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The error showed the specific code that was causing the problem.

Comment: I'll always be sure in include it in the future. Regardless we got a new New error: name 'client_acc_num' is not defined

Comment: Fixed. Was another view class. With old variable. Unfortunately, none of the variables are being saved with the test GET parameters. Example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/webhook/?clientAccnum=900&clientSubacc=123 I used print (hook.client_acc_num, hook.client_sub_acc, hook.time_stamp_local) to debug in the console and it clearly shows the variables are pulled from the URL.

Comment: But those aren't the names of your fields - those are `clientAccNum`, `clientSubacc` etc.

Comment: Nice that fixed it! Thanks for the help